# Не видит почему то идентификатор

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Как обьявить переменную arrrDoubt в функции? Вроде скармливаю, а оно всё равно не видит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала замените картинки текстом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объявили функцию `IndexParity`, в которую передаете переменную `x` - вот с ней и работайте, а не с `arrDoubl` - никакого `arrDoubl` ваша `IndexParity` знать не знает. Когда вы ее вызовете, передав `arrDoubl` - она о ней узнает как об аргументе `x`.

Короче,

```
arrdOubl[n] > 2
```

замените не

```
x[n] > 2
```

и перечитайте свои конспекты, что такое параметры функций.